# How can I assign a val with the implementation of a trait?

Tags: scala, traits

I have the following trait and classes:

```
trait A{
  def func1: String
  def func2: Int
}
```

```
class F extends A{
  def func1: String = ???
  def func2: Int = ???
}
```

```
class G extends A{
  def func1: String = ???
  def func2: Int = ???
}
```

And I want to create the following trait and class:

```
trait X{
  val a: ***
}
```

```
class Z extends X{
  override val a = new G
}
```

What do I need to write on '***' in trait X so that I can assign val a with a class F or G ?
Thank you.

EDIT

Sorry, I forgot to mention that trait A is A[Any] and traits F and G can be 'F extends A[String]' and 'G extends A[Int]'. In other words, the classes can extends the trait A with different types of parameters.

Comment: Does `val a: A` not work for you? Also in Scala we define a value member in super class/trait using `def` instead of `val`

Comment: Do you want users of `X` to know which specific `A` did they got? or should they just depend on the interface?

Comment: @texasbruce It shows 'Required: A, Found: G'

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez No, they just need to get an implementation of A and use the func1 and func2. Regardless of whether it is class G or F, class Z must be able to use func1 and func2

Comment: This seems to work: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/6O4eSN9jRWWQTfUDGjsHjQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re. your edit, your code fails because trait A only takes type parameter of a fixed type. If you declare base class having a `A[Any]`, you cannot override it with a `A[Int]` or `A[String]`. There are two ways to make your code works.

One is to make trait A type argument `covariant`, so that you can override with subclass of the type argument you declared in base class (note the `+` in trait A definition):

```
  trait A[+T]
  class F extends A[String]
  class G extends A[Int]
  
  trait X {
    val a: A[Any]
  }
  
  class Z extends X {
    val a = new G
  }
```

See here: [Sample](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/EB8H0AoeSFGLAVFzSh3oxw)

Another way to work is to declare a as a `A[_]` (`_` means it takes any type as a parameter, which is different from `Any`):

```
  trait A[T]
  class F extends A[String]
  class G extends A[Int]
  
  trait X {
    val a: A[_]
  }
  
  class Z extends X {
    val a = new G
  }
```

See here: [Sample](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/fB2qWWHSQL2RyKbcedTIzw)

Comment: I would say that the best solution would be to make `X` also generic. Since both **Any** as well as existentials are not very useful _(in general)_.